# MSMQ and IIS7.0 Permissions

Tags: permissions, iis-7, msmq

I've installed MSMQ on our publicly hosted Windows 2008 Server, which already hosts IIS, and a number of websites (that we control).

I've created a private MSMQ queue.

However, in order for my ASMX web service to read/write to the private MSMQ queue, I've had to grant IIS_USRS SendMessage and ReceiveMessage rights.

Is this correct in terms of setting permissions and user rights accessing this private queue.    Also, can this queue be accessed remotely ?

Is there anyway I can verify this ?  Basically I only want any website/service running from the server to have access to the private queue.

Comment: I assume you found the answers you needed?